# Android: Open file extension ONLY with my App

Tags: android, file, explorer

i have an android app, which imports and exports zip files. When exporting, the app creates a zip file with the extension (lets say) .xyz123

Now,when I go to the explorer and click on the file (e.g)  text.xyz13 , android offers multiple apps to open my file.

Question: HOW-TO manage, that the file will only be opened by my app ?

thx a lot :)

Comment: I don't think you can *prevent* other apps from showing as an option to handle an intent. That would give your app too much power and would cause problems if some other app also attempts to prevent your app from handling it. In the end, the user is in control - not your app.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens ok thanks. if so, i have to trust user, to click on my app =)

Answer (score 1):

> that the file will only be opened by my app ?

Don't have the file on external storage in the first place.

If the user can get to the file via some sort of "explorer", then the *user* gets to decide what to do with that file, just as they can on any other operating system.

Moreover, the typical role of "imports and exports" is to *allow* the user to do whatever they want with the file.

Comment: i let the user export via mail/bluetooth. and the recipient can open this file (which will lie somewhere like "downloads") and all the stuff will be importet

offtopic: is there any possibility to get the directory of the zipfile, when recipient clicks on it?

Comment: @user2585063: "is there any possibility to get the directory of the zipfile, when recipient clicks on it?" -- if the user elects to launch one of your activities, `getIntent().getData()` in that activity will give you a `Uri` pointing to the file. If that `Uri` is a `file:///` `Uri`, you get the full path.